# hitting a pool ball at exactly 90 degrees

Tags: trigonometry

So a friend and I had an argument and I thought I might get some unbiased proof here. Is it possible to hit a pool ball with another pool ball at exactly 90 degrees. Ie if I had a white ball could I hit another ball to go exactly in a perpendicular direction to the white ball?

Comment: Yes and no. You'd have to hit exactly tangentially and the resulting speed would be exactly zero. (I assume you mean perpendicular to the *original* direction o fth ewhite ball)

Comment: But would it impact. Imo it would not impact. Ie if it were to hit it was by definition not tangential (

Comment: And yes. Thats what I meant

Comment: Its more a theoretical question. I would argue that 89.99999... degrees is possible but not 90 degrees

Comment: Just use a masse shot to curve the ball, that will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless the ball you strike is able (or allowed) to change direction before it hits the second ball, (i.e. by bouncing off a cushion) the answer is no. This is due to conservation of momentum and energy. Consider the white ball of mass $m_w$ travelling along a horizontal plane with velocity $v$. The second ball, with mass $m_s$ is initially stationary, so has velocity 0. If the second ball were travelling at right angles to the white ball after impact with velocity $w$, by conservation of momentum, the momentum of the white ball is now $m_w*v-m_s*w$, and for the second ball it is $m_s*w$. But here you have created energy from nowhere - the total kinetic energy of the balls is now greater after the impact than it was before the impact, a contradiction.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind the eqaution for the ne momentum of the white ball and why does this not apply to other angles that is valid?

Comment: Ok ignore the above comment. I understand how you get the white ball and second balls momentum but do not understand how you conclude that the total kinetic energy is more?

Comment: @Murdock Say the white ball starts moving noth and the other ball is caused to move west. Then the white ball must still have *the same* northbound speed *plus* some eastbound speed. Hnece the white ball is faster after the impact, i.e. has more energy than it had before (when it was the only bearer of kinetic energy). - Interestingly, Edward's argument does not even require the two balls to have the same mass.

Comment: Ah got it. Makes complete sense thanks guys.